# Apache stopping

Tags: drivers, apache2, postgresql

I am running Ubuntu22.04 on an EC2 VM. I have created a module to run under Apache, but there are 2 strange things happening.
First, is that although it works fine during the day, overnight at some point it stops and the only way to get it up again is to restart apache. The app is VERY simple. Currently all it does is connect to Postgresql 15, and write a line to a table.
the second thing which is happening is when I start or restart apache, my module gets run 3 times, every single time.
I dont know if the above are related or not.
Im am not an ubuntu expert, so please be kind :)
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks